# Dart - named parameters using a Map

Tags: dart

I would like to know if I can call a function with name parameters using a map e.g.

```dart
void main()
{
  Map a = {'m':'done'}; // Map with EXACTLY the same keys as slave named param.
  slave(a);
}
void slave({String m:'not done'}) //Here I should have some type control
{ 
  print(m); //should print done
}
```

the hack here is to not use kwargs but a Map or, if you care about types, some interfaced class (just like Json-obj), but wouldn't be more elegant to just have it accept map as kwars?
More, using this hack, optional kwargs would probably become a pain...
IMHO a possible implementation, if it does not exist yet, would be something like:

```
slave(kwargs = a)
```

e.g. Every function that accepts named param could silently accept a (Map) kwargs (or some other name) argument, if defined dart should, under the hood, take care of this logic: if the key in the Map are exactly the non optional ones, plus some of the optional ones, defined in the {} brackets, and of compatible types "go on".

Answer (score 25):

You can use [Function.apply](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Function/apply.html) to do something similar :

```dart
main() {
  final a = new Map<Symbol, dynamic>();
  a[const Symbol('m')] = 'done';
  Function.apply(slave, [], a);
}
```

You can also extract an helper method to simplify the code :

```dart
main() {
  final a = symbolizeKeys({'m':'done'});
  Function.apply(slave, [], a);
}

Map<Symbol, dynamic> symbolizeKeys(Map<String, dynamic> map){
  return map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(Symbol(k), v));
}
```

Comment: Ok, just what I was searching :)

Comment: Worth noting that calling "new Symbol()" makes it harder for dart2js to minify your code. It could lead to your js output being bloated.You may be better off changing slave() to take a Map as an argument.

Comment: How to use this to constructor?

Comment: Since some values maybe other "objects", I wonder if we could make this recursive using reflection to infer the type of named parameter.

Comment: Tried it out and it's great. This will cut down my code considerably since I can just pass a map. Although it's a shame it has to use Symbol instead of just String.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @alexandre-ardhuin is correct but is missing something : How to call a constructor as Function.
You have to use the property `new` after the Classname. Here's an example :

```
main() {
  final a =  new Map<Symbol, dynamic>();
  Function.apply(MyClass.new, [], a);
}
```