# Map to Class in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a standard way to convert a map to an object of a user defined class?

In Python you can do MyClass(**map) which basically unwraps the map into named arguments of the constructor of the class.

Any pointers/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

You can also achieve this manually by using [named constructor](https://www.dartlang.org/resources/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-11) like this simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Map myMap = {"Users": [

  {"Name": "Mark", "Email": "mark@email"},


  {"Name": "Rick", "Email": "rick@email"},
]
};

class MyData {
  String name;
  String email;

  MyData.fromJson(Map json){
    this.name = json["Name"];
    this.email = json ["Email"];
  }
}

class UserList extends StatelessWidget {
  MyData data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("User List"),),
        body:
        new ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: myMap["Users"].length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              data = new MyData.fromJson(myMap["Users"][index]);
              return new Text("${data.name} ${data.email}");
            })
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why they don't just make this built in.  Gotta be some way since this is supposed to replace js!

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in way.
You can use one of the serialization packages like

- https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable
- https://pub.dev/packages/built_value
- ...

Answer (score 0):

[You can use Function.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16690274/2234013). I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/micimize/67e428dca235e26b84c193d403a6b643) to test it out the linked answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern I just came up with that appears to work initially. I will report back if it breaks.

```
class Foo {
  String bar;
  User user;

  Foo({
    required this.bar,
    required this.user,
  });

  @override
  Map toJson() => {
        'bar': bar,
        'user': user,
      };

  static Foo fromJson(Map json) {
    return Foo(bar: json['bar'], user: json['user']);
  }
}
```

The first constructor

```
Foo({
    required this.bar,
    required this.user,
  });
```

allows you to declare instances with this syntax:

```
Foo testFoo = Foo(bar: 'foo', user: User(name:'dummy', age: 23));
```

The second function

```
@override
  Map toJson() => {
        'bar': bar,
        'user': user,
      };
```

is an instance method that allows you to convert the class to what is for most intents and purposes a JSON object, though in Dart the name for it is a Map<dynamic,dynamic>, or a Map with dynamic keys and dynamic values.

The third function

```
static Foo fromJson(Map json) {
    return Foo(bar: json['bar'], user: json['user']);
  }
```

is another constructor that can be called as a static method. It takes in the same type that the toJson instance method returns. This effectively allows you to serialize and deserialize your data types into and out of the structures used to represent JSON objects in the http library's request methods.

Let me know if you have problems. I'm invested in the stability of this solution.