# Flutter : Called the Arguments as Object using Navigator pushNamed

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using MaterialApp with router to navigate to the next screen, i'm Using this for navigate to another screen with passing the Arguments :

```
onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                DetailDebt.routedName,
                                arguments: {
                                  'receiverName': debtListView.receiverName,
                                  'amount': debtListView.amount,
                                  'dateReturn': debtListView.dateReturn,
                                  'pathImage': debtListView.imageReceiver,
                                  'signatureImage': debtListView.imageSignature,
                                },
                              ),
```

In the next screen i'm make variable to store the argument like this :

```
final Map arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
  return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Text(
          arguments['receiverName'],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

My question is , How to store the Argument in variable then i can call it something like this  :

```
// I want Store the Arguments in the variable , so i can call it something like this  : 
final Map arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
final loadedArguments = arguments; // <= ???
  return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Text(
          loadedArguments.receiverName,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And It's My Model if you need it :

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'debt_model_hive.g.dart';

@HiveType()
class DebtModelHive extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String receiverName;
  @HiveField(1)
  int amount;
  @HiveField(2)
  DateTime dateReturn;
  @HiveField(3)
  String imageReceiver;
  @HiveField(4)
  Uint8List imageSignature;

  DebtModelHive({
    this.receiverName,
    this.amount,
    this.dateReturn,
    this.imageReceiver,
    this.imageSignature,
  });
  // Hive fields go here
}
```

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you a simple example how to pass arguments to your page. Here I push a new named route with int value in arguments:

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('my_route', arguments: 100);
},
```

In my `MaterialApp` I set `onGenerateRoute` parameter to generate a new route with given arguments:

```dart
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case 'my_route': return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => HomePage(settings.arguments as int), // passing arguments
      settings: settings,
    );
    default: throw Exception('Unknown route');
  }
},
```

Now I can access the value inside of `build` method:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int arguments;

  HomePage(this.arguments, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    value = widget.arguments;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Value from arguments: ${widget.arguments}');
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the value from route's arguments inside of `initState` like this:

```dart
  int value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        value = ModalRoute.of(this.context).settings?.arguments;
      });
      print('setting value from route arguments');
    });
  }
```

Though, it's pretty dirty and I don't recommend doing this.

Comment: In your example **builder: (context) => HomePage(settings.arguments as int)**. It's only 1 argument passed, but how to I passing multiple argument like my above question?

Comment: @ZeffryReynando You can pass any object you want as arguments, for example Map or create your class and instantiate an object of this class. `int` is just an example.

Comment: Let me make this clear for me , for example I pass the argument in pushNamed using Map like my questions. So in onGenerateRoute I write like this **HomePage(settings.arguments as Map)** right? And my question how to initiated in HomePage ?

Comment: @ZeffryReynando That's right. You can use this value in `initState` to init a variable or just access it in `build`.

Comment: Like this : final Map arguments; HomePage({this.arguments}); Now I don't know make the argument object,and I can call it like this : arguments.receiverName,arguments.amount, arguments.dateReturn etc

Comment: @ZeffryReynando You should create class that will contain these fields and use the values from map to init the object. You have to do it either manually or use code generators like json_serializable or built_value. There's no way to do it automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523725/dart-map-to-class

Comment: Thank's , I got the point. I create this `factory DebtModelHive.fromJson(Map json) {
    return DebtModelHive(
      receiverName: json["receiverName"],
      amount: json["amount"],
      dateReturn: json["dateReturn"],
      imageReceiver: json["imageReceiver"],
      imageSignature: json["imageSignature"],
    );
  }`, 
And in detail page 
```final Map arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
    var loadedDebt = DebtModelHive.fromJson(arguments);```