# What is k,v in Map in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

`Map<String,String>` means key and value of the map should be string and also `State<StatefullClassName>` so that we can access the StateFull class variables using widgets attribute in state class. How it sets the String data type to the key when we give `Map<String,dynamic>`

Answer (score 0):

## Initialize a Map with values in Dart/Flutter

The examples show you how to:

- initialize Map in simple way using {} (curly braces).
- create a Map with all key/value pairs of other Map using from(), of() constructor.
- create a new Map from the given keys and values using fromIterables().
- create Map in which keys and values are computed using fromIterable()
- create a ‘const’ Map using unmodifiable() constructor.

  ```
  Map<String, int> map1 = {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2};
  print(map1);

  // not specify key-value type
  Map map2 = {'zero': 0, 'I': 'one', 10: 'X'};
  print(map2);

  var map3 = {'zero': 0, 'I': 'one', 10: 'X'};
  print(map3);
  ```

### Output:

```
{zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2}
{zero: 0, I: one, 10: X}
{zero: 0, I: one, 10: X}
```

You can check this [link](https://bezkoder.com/dart-map/) for more. I hope you will get this. Thank you.

Comment: Yes , what i am trying to ask is if i want to develop my own data structures like map. How can i get  type object <String,String> . For example flutter redux we have to pass the object we created as a data type . So how

Comment: May be you are looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47535595/1318946