# Is it possible to add a json in the properties an element?

Tags: flutter

I have a json like this:

```
    Map<String, dynamic> optionsContainer() {
      return {
        "color": Colors.red,
        "height": MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.40,
        "margin": EdgeInsets.all(10)
      };
    }
.
.
.
 Container(
  child:Text("mytext"),
  optionsContainer(),
 )
```

I get an error when I try to assign it to the properties of an element, in this case a `container`

Is there any way of doing this?

I am getting this error:

"Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments."

my idea is to recycle code and define these properties in a class so as not to repeat them again.

NOTE: I don't do this with a `theme` because this is only for one class within my app I don't want it to overwrite the other styles.

Comment: I think perhaps the "real" task is "how to expand a dictionary to named paramters?" (https://stackoverflow.com/q/16688054/2864740) or even even "how to assign properties from an object?"

Comment: @user2864740 excuse my ignorance, I am new to this. I did not understand how to do in my case.

Comment: where is Container's  child ? 

 Container(
  child : optionsContainer(),
 )

Comment: @Nickan I updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know all possible keys in map, you can extract values and pass them as usual named parameters:

```
final options = optionsContainer();
```

```
Container(
  color: options["color"],
  height: options["height"],
  margin: options["margin"],
)
```

---

Alternatively you can make a class for container data and use it instead of map which gives compile-time types check:

```
class ContainerData {
  final Color color;
  final double height;
  final EdgeInsets margin;

  ContainerData({
    @required this.color,
    @required this.height,
    @required this.margin,
  });
}
```

```
ContainerData getOptions() {
  return ContainerData(
    color: Colors.red,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.40,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  );
}
```

```
final options = getOptions();
```

```
Container(
  color: options.color,
  height: options.height,
  margin: options.margin,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what happens if you don't put the `@ required`

Comment: If named constructor argument isn't `@required`, you can omit it when creating class instance without any warnings, e.g.`ContainerData(color: Colors.red, margin: EdgeInsets.all(10))`: height is omitted. If an argument is optional by design, then `@required` shouldn't be used